# Typical scheduling time quantum in modern operating systems

Tags: timer, kernel, scheduling

What are typical durations of an operating system process/thread scheduling quantum? I realize that this can vary with the scheduling algorithm, priorities, workloads, hardware, etc., so I'm expecting answers to come with conditions/assumptions, or to be ballpark.

I can find examples that seem to suggest something on the order of 16 milliseconds from various OS class notes found via Google, but I have no idea how grounded in reality these examples are.

Answer (score 3):

According to answers to this question: [How to know linux scheduler time slice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16401294/how-to-know-linux-scheduler-time-slice)

Linux will change the timeslice based on latency goals, but defaults to somewhere between 0.75 ms and 6 ms.

Acoording to answers to this question: https://superuser.com/questions/1326252/changing-windows-thread-sheduler-timeslice

Windows uses timeslices between 20 msec and 120 msec, depending on the version of windows and whether the program in question is in the foreground.

Answer (score -1):

The period of time for which a process is allowed to run uninterrupted in a pre-emptive multitasking operating system.

Comment: The OP asked about practical durations of quanta, not the definition of the term.