# How to know linux scheduler time slice?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, procfs

I'm looking for the value of the time slice (or quantum) of my Linux kernel.

Specific Questions:

- Is there a `/proc` file which expose such an information ?
- (Or) Is it well-defined in the Linux header of my distributions ?
- (Or) Is there a C function of the Linux API (maybe sysinfo) that expose this value ?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The quantum allocated for a particular process [may vary](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel/1346063):

> You can tune "slice" by adjusting **sched_latency_ns** and
>   **sched_min_granularity_ns**, but note that "slice" is not a fixed
>   quantum.  Also note that CFS preemption decisions are based upon
>   instantaneous state.  A task may have received a full (variable)
>   "slice" of CPU time, but preemption will be triggered only if a more
>   deserving task is available, so a "slice" is not the "max
>   uninterrupted CPU time" that you may expect it to be.. but it is
>   somewhat similar.

This is because the [Completely Fair Scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_Fair_Scheduler), the default Linux scheduler, [assigns a proportion of the processor](https://notes.eddyerburgh.me/operating-systems/linux/process-scheduling#timeslice) to a process rather than a fixed timeslice. That means the timeslice for each process is [proportional to the current load and weighted by the process' priority value](https://notes.eddyerburgh.me/operating-systems/linux/process-scheduling#fair-scheduling).

For special-purpose realtime processes which use SCHED_RR, the default timeslice is defined in the Linux kernel as `RR_TIMESLICE` in [include/linux/sched/rt.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/sched/rt.h).

```
/*
 * default timeslice is 100 msecs (used only for SCHED_RR tasks).
 * Timeslices get refilled after they expire.
 */
#define RR_TIMESLICE            (100 * HZ / 1000)
```

You can use [`sched_rr_get_interval()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_rr_get_interval) to get the SCHED_RR interval for a specific SCHED_RR process.

Comment: However it seems that `rt.h` appeared with Linux kernel 3.9.

Comment: Before **Linux kernel v3.9**, the definition of `RR_TIMESLICE` was located in [include/linux/sched.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/sched.h?v=3.8#L1227). Before **Linux kernel v3.4**, the definition was named `DEF_TIMESLICE` and was located in [kernel/sched/sched.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sched/sched.h?v=3.3#L43).

Comment: Note that this answer concerns only threads scheduled with the realtime priority RR

Comment: Excuse me. Isn't 100 * 100 = 10000, and 10,000/1000 = 10? So how is that 100 msecs?

Comment: @Abundance The comment `default timeslice is 100 msecs` may be referring to a kernel configured with `CONFIG_HZ=1000`; in this case `(100 * (1000) / 1000)` is equal to `100`.

Comment: Interesting. But how are processes able to send new data to the monitor 60 times per second if each slice lasts up to 100ms? Surely the process needs to be asked for graphical output more frequently than this?

Comment: @goblin When a process is available to be scheduled, the Linux scheduler will evaluate whether the current process should be preempted. For your hypothetical case of a process sending data to the monitor 60 times per second, it would likely preempt the other process since it's used a smaller proportion of the CPU so far; the CFS scheduler tries to schedule processes so that each has a proportional usage of CPU time based on their priority value.

Comment: @goblin If the process is SCHED_RR rather than SCHED_NORMAL, then yes you might have a problem if you have a process with a higher priority that is using up all 100ms without yielding. Most processes however will have periods where they wait for some sort of I/O or other blocking operation, so they will end up yielding the processor to lower priority tasks.

Answer (score 44):

CFS (which is default scheduler for processes) has no fixed timeslice, it is calculated at runtime depending of targeted latency (`sysctl_sched_latency`) and number of running processes. Timeslice could never be less than minimum granularity (`sysctl_sched_min_granularity`).

Timeslice will be always between `sysctl_sched_min_granularity` and `sysctl_sched_latency`, which are defaults to 0.75 ms and 6 ms respectively and defined in [kernel/sched/fair.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/sched/fair.c#L93).

But actual timeslice isn't exported to user-space.

Comment: Is this true for batch processes too?

Comment: This is true to every process that run under CFS scheduler (not real-time process)

Comment: @user239558 excellent point. The SCHED_BATCH timeslice is longer - 1.5 seconds.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/31286586/799204

Answer (score 12):

There is some confusion in the accepted answer between `SCHED_OTHER` processes (i.e., those operating under the (default) non-realtime round-robin timesharing policy) and `SCHED_RR` processes.

The `sched_latency_ns` and `sched_min_granularity_ns` files (which are intended for debugging purposes, and visible only if the kernel is configured with `CONFIG_SCHED_DEBUG`) affect the scheduling of `SCHED_OTHER` processes. As noted in Alexey Shmalko's answer, the time slice under CFS is not fixed (and not exported to user space), and will depend on kernel parameters and factors such as the process's nice value.

[sched_rr_get_interval()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_rr_get_interval.2.html) returns a fixed value which is the quantum that a `SCHED_RR` process is guaranteed to get, unless it is preempted or blocks. On traditional Linux, the `SCHED_RR` quantum is 0.1 seconds. Since Linux 3.9, the limit is [adjustable](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_rr_get_interval.2.html#NOTES) via the `/proc/sys/kernel/sched_rr_timeslice_ms` file, where the quantum is expressed as a millisecond value whose default is 100.

Answer (score 11):

I attemped to google this question's same doubt of time slice of `SCHED_RR` in Linux, but I did not get clear answer both from here and the kernel's source code.

After further checking, I found the **key point is `RR_TIMESLICE` is the default time slice in jiffies**, not millisecond! So, the default time slice of `SCHED_RR` is always 100ms, no matter what `HZ` you've configured.

Same as the value of `/proc/sys/kernel/sched_rr_timeslice_ms`, which input value is in **milliseconds**, but it stores and outputs in **jiffies**!

So, when your `CONFIG_HZ=100` is set, you'll find that:

```
# echo 100 > /proc/sys/kernel/sched_rr_timeslice_ms
# cat /proc/sys/kernel/sched_rr_timeslice_ms
10
```

It's little bit confused, hope this can help you to understand it!

Comment: Mine matched up, maybe they fixed it... :)

Answer (score 6):

`sysctl` is used to read and write kernel parameters at runtime. The parameters available are those listed under `/proc/sys/` . Also Linux 3.9 added a new mechanism for adjusting (and viewing) the [SCHED_RR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9392415/linux-sched-other-sched-fifo-and-sched-rr-differences) quantum: the /proc/sys/kernel/sched_rr_timeslice_ms file exposes the quantum as a millisecond value, whose default is 100. Writing 0 to this file resets the quantum to the default value. So you might want to try:

```
sysctl kernel.sched_rr_timeslice_ms
```