# Get process's timeslice in user mode

Tags: linux, c, scheduling, user-interface

How can I get the value of process's timeslice in user mode? I designed a new scheduling policy, and I want to check if processes with the same policy (my policy) have the same timeslice to run. It is not a real-time process.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to know linux scheduler time slice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16401294/how-to-know-linux-scheduler-time-slice)

Answer (score 1):

You can see this in

`/proc/<pid>/stat`

14th and 15th fields represent the utime and stime respectively. utime is time spent in user mode while stime represents time spent by process in kernel mode.