# What is difference between sched_batch and sched_other scheduling?

Tags: linux, operating-system, scheduling

I am working on Ubuntu project. Have not found clear difference between sched_batch and sched_other. Can anyone tell me the difference?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Threads that are scheduled with `sched_batch` are assumed to be non-interactive, but CPU bound and optimized for throughput. Thus, this policy is more cache-friendly. The default `sched_batch` timeslice is 1.5 seconds. In addition, in case of SMP, `sched_batch` will migrate to a core with high idleness (with respect to non-batch threads).