# How do I debug where a tokio task is hanging?

Tags: linux, asynchronous, rust, strace

I'm having trouble debugging random hangups in my polling code for *exactly* 11ms.  This is happening across multiple servers, with different hardware configs and operating systems (and no shared resource for the code in question), so I'm inclined to believe its in my code.

Essentially I have a bunch of in-flight TCP requests that I have as futures in a list.  My polling function is checking through them and sending results over a channel.  It works fine most of the time, but occasionally will pause for exactly 11ms, and then continue.

Normally the Waker is scheduled by the underlying TCP connection, as well as the channel that pushes requests into the queue.  But for debugging purposes I've added a busy-loop that *always* schedules the Waker immediately.

Using the busy loop, I'd expect a constant stream of poll() calls, and normally that is the case.  However, when one of these hiccups happens, I see what looks like the thread get paused/preempted and then re-started 11ms later.

A few examples of places the pause has happened, that I wouldn't expect it to:

```
2023-09-26T23:29:54.354627Z  WARN database::backends: checking pending: 1
2023-09-26T23:29:54.354637Z  WARN database::backends: poll future... Pending
2023-09-26T23:29:54.365740Z  WARN database::backends: done (not ready!) future
```

Which comes from the following code:

```
            let fut_polled = fut.poll_unpin(cx);
            warn!("poll future... {:?}", fut_polled);
            if let Poll::Ready((x, y, z)) = fut_polled {
              warn!("future ready");
... snipped...
            }
            warn!("done (not ready!) future");
```

Can see it successfully polled the underlying future, and when doing a simple if-let on the Poll result, gets suspended for 11ms.  I would expect `future ready` or `done (not ready!) future` to be executed immediately.

Another example is:

```
2023-09-26T23:25:07.669470Z  WARN database::backends: poll
2023-09-26T23:25:07.680708Z  WARN database::backends: poll loop!
```

Which comes from:

```
  fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
    warn!("poll");
    let pin = self.get_mut();
    loop {
      warn!("poll loop!");
```

Which again, I wouldn't expect any delay on, `self.get_mut()` is just returning the underlying Pin pointer, which shouldn't take any time.

This happens often enough to be easily reproducible (every few seconds under light load), but rare enough that strace generates a LOT of difficult to sift through data.  This is also in a much larger application, and I haven't had any luck making a small reproducible case.

The thread running the poll loop is started as such:

```
    let _ = std::thread::Builder::new()
      .name("database-thread".to_string())
      .spawn(move || {
        let rt = tokio::runtime::Builder::new_current_thread()
          .enable_all()
          .build()
          .expect("failed to create tokio runtime");

        rt.block_on(async move { handler.await });
      })
      .expect("failed to spawn database thread");
```

The server itself isn't heavily loaded (plenty of spare ram, low cpu usage, plenty of cores)...

How do I go about debugging what's pausing my thread, and why its *always* 11ms even across different servers?

Edit: Adding some strace data...

```
[pid 4056498] 20:34:14.995277 write(1, "\33[2m2023-09-27T00:34:14.995272Z\33"..., 1402023-09-27T00:34:14.995272Z  WARN database::backends: poll future... Pending
 <unfinished ...>
[pid 4056497] 20:34:14.995283 write(11, "{\"id\":[snipped]"..., 192 <unfinished ...>
[pid 4056498] 20:34:14.995289 <... write resumed>) = 140 <0.000007>
[pid 4056497] 20:34:14.995293 <... write resumed>) = 192 <0.000006>
[pid 4056498] 20:34:14.995298 write(1, "\33[2m2023-09-27T00:34:14.995294Z\33"..., 1422023-09-27T00:34:14.995294Z  WARN database::backends: done (not ready!) future
 <unfinished ...>
[pid 4056501] 20:34:14.995304 <... epoll_wait resumed>[{events=EPOLLOUT, data={u32=2752585088, u64=2699992046976}}], 1024, 3) = 1 <0.000574>
[pid 4056497] 20:34:14.995309 epoll_wait(20,  <unfinished ...>
[pid 4056501] 20:34:14.995315 epoll_wait(3,  <unfinished ...>
[pid 4056498] 20:34:15.006650 <... write resumed>) = 142 <0.000016>
[pid 4056501] 20:34:15.006668 <... epoll_wait resumed>[{events=EPOLLIN|EPOLLOUT, data={u32=2752585088, u64=2699992046976}}], 1024, 2) = 1 <0.011350>
[pid 4056501] 20:34:15.006689 write(22, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8 <unfinished ...>
[pid 4056498] 20:34:15.006696 write(1, "\33[2m2023-09-27T00:34:15.006681Z\33"..., 135 <unfinished ...>
2023-09-27T00:34:15.006681Z  WARN database::backends: poll loop finished
```

Can see the same lines as above (`done (not ready!) future`), the next line after it is just on the other side of a loop end, pseudocode:

```
loop {
  log("poll future");
  if (ready) {
    ...
  } else {
    log("done (not ready!) future");
  }
}
log("poll loop finished");
```

So in between that `else` log, and the end of the loop log, strace is doing two `epoll_wait()`s, and pausing for 11ms.

Edit: When the epoll_wait() happens, its specifically waiting on `anon_inode:[eventpoll]` for example:

```
[pid 4057391] 20:53:44.862936 epoll_wait(19<anon_inode:[eventpoll]>,  <unfinished ...>
[pid 4057360] 20:53:44.862949 <... epoll_wait resumed>[{events=EPOLLOUT, data={u32=1511071104, u64=2660095827328}}], 1024, 2) = 1 <0.011111>
```

Whats the next step in debugging this?

Comment: Use tokio console to debug the runtime tasks

Comment: Check out [tokio-console](https://github.com/tokio-rs/console). I haven't used it myself, but I understand it is designed to help track down blocking issues like this.

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't show any additional information... Doesn't paste well here, but shows the busy loop running non-stop:
│Busy: 1m36s (98.67%)
Scheduled: 1.30s (1.33%)
Idle: 27.02µs (0.00%)

Comment: Based on your strace output, the `epoll` is likely unrelated or hitting the same symptoms. You can see that it is on a separate thread. So the `write` to stdout took 11ms. Is your application I/O constrained?

Comment: Typically not (or at least I'd think not), maybe 10-20 lines of output per second normally?  That said, I've been adding an insane amount of logging, so its very possible it is now.  But the issue exists with logging turned off (just harder to track down).  I'll see if I can reproduce an strace with logging turned off (and actually find it in the trace...)

Comment: If you can distill you code down to a small-ish example that reproduces the hiccup (an [MCVE](/help/minimal-reproducible-example)), that'd be ideal to post. I'd be very interested. Otherwise it may be difficult to get a definite answer.

Comment: Could that simply be the OS scheduling another process/thread to run?

Comment: Obviously _could_ be, but 11ms seems like a long time to be off-core.  These are (reasonably) beefy boxes, 12-16 core, and this happens plenty often when they're under low load.  I'd expect a core to be available at almost all times...

Comment: Note that the Linux scheduler doesn't like moving threads between cores, so it will sometimes block threads for a little while when their core is busy even if there's another core that's available rather than moving them immediately. You can do a whole system trace with [lttng](https://lttng.org/) to see if that's what's happening.

Comment: @Jmb I'll try to get lttng running and see if that gives me any info (first time seeing it, looks neat!).  A tiny bit more info in the meantime.  It definitely seems like something OS specific.  I instrumented the service (in golang) that I'm experiencing latency to, and I've seen both the rust-side take 11ms (while the golang side processed at a normal speed, 100us or so), as well as the opposite case, where the golang side itself took 11ms to process a result.  Makes me think the kernel is pausing threads for too long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can see it successfully polled the underlying future, and when doing a simple if-let on the Poll result, gets suspended for 11ms. I would expect future ready or done (not ready!) future to be executed immediately.

The `if let` is extremely unlikely to be causing the delay here, especially because your `warn!` statement already contains the result returned by `poll_unpin`. Therefore, the delay likely occurs during the logging statement which in all likelihood takes way longer than the other statement there.

If you want to test how your program behaves during normal execution it might be better to store some statistics. For example you could track the time between each iteration and count the number of times the iteration time exceeds 10ms and then output the count once in a while. This technique can be used to ensure that the problems you are currently observing aren't being caused by the logging statements themselves. And that does not seem like a stretch: logging at every iteration in a busy loop is asking for trouble. When is this stuff going to be committed to the logs? Which thread is going to do that? Does this thread need to acquire a lock before it can commit this large an amount of data?

> Obviously could be, but 11ms seems like a long time to be off-core. These are (reasonably) beefy boxes, 12-16 core, and this happens plenty often when they're under low load. I'd expect a core to be available at almost all times...

Generally speaking 11ms is not that long if there are other threads that want to run on the same core. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16401294/how-to-know-linux-scheduler-time-slice#:%7E:text=Timeslice%20will%20be%20always%20between,in%20kernel%2Fsched%2Ffair.). Especially if you care about latency you might want to see how you can tweak the scheduler settings to see how you can avoid off-core time as much as possible.

Your server might seem idle but perhaps there could be outside events that trigger lots of things to happen at the same time, making it more occupied for a brief moment. For example, there could be multiple requests coming in or these requests could spawn multiple different threads. Besides, there is the fact that moving to a different core carries the cost of a lot of cache misses so is often delayed by the scheduler.

In short, here are some good next steps:

1. When doing performance tracing, make sure the performance tracing does not worsen the load too much. Replace logging in the busy loop by some light-weight bookkeeping.
2. Investigate your scheduler settings, especially if you care about latency.
3. Investigate which other threads are running on the same core and if possible, ensure that they run on different cores.

Comment: A lot of what you're saying is spot on.  This application is something that does nothing 99.9% of the time, and when a request comes in, has a burst of work to do as quickly as possible.  Typically we're trying to keep the latency under 1ms.  Occasionally it needs to fetch data from the other process (~100us), and thats what showed this originally was very sparse logging (whole request) that was bucketed oddly.  98% of the requests finished in 1ms, 1% in 2ms, and then the last 1% at _exactly_ 11ms.  I'll start digging deeper into the scheduler to see if that's part of it...

Comment: At least I have perf data to make me feel less crazy.  Recorded a section with `perf sched record`, and in `perf sched timehist` I see a  _lot_ of tokio tasks listed as 'wait' of 11ms.  If you ignore the ugly bash chopping, aggregating the 'wait' column from timehist, I see a _large_ spike at 11ms (`for i in {0..20}; do grep 'tokio' out | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f 5 | grep "^$i\." | wc -l; done`) gives me: 19515
111
70
48
56
44
41
53
53
42
45
660
4
2
1
2
1
0
2
0
3
Obviously a large number at <1ms, a few all the way up, and then a LARGE jump at 11ms (and ~nothing after)